# Draw Rectangle on QPixMap by: First Click to define first corner, move mouse and keep drawing, and Second Click to define the shape

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like draw a rectangle above QPixmap on QLabel (with PyQT5). My purpose is the next:

- **First Click:** To define the top-left corner.
- **Move mouse:** To draw a rectangle that depends on the position of mouse. Only one rectangle.
- **Second Click:** To confirm the position of the bottom-right corner and draw the definitive rectangle.

Actually, I have a code than allows do the actions of **First Click and Second Click, but not drawing while move the mouse**. I have used the *paintEvent and mousePresEvent*.

```
        pixmap_ed = QPixmap(f"{self.image}")
        pixmap_ed_scaled = pixmap_ed.scaled(int(self.QLabel.width()), int(self.QLabel.height()), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.QLabel.setPixmap(pixmap_ed_scaled)

    def paintEvent(self,event):
        if self.flag_dibujar == True and self.primer_click == 1 and self.segundo_click == 1:
            painter = QPainter(self.QLabel.pixmap())
            pen = QPen()
            pen.setColor(QtGui.QColor('green'))
            pen.setWidth(3)
            painter.setPen(pen)

            painter.drawRect(self.beginX,self.beginY, self.endX-self.beginX,self.endY-self.beginY)
            self.update()
            self.QLabel.update()

            self.primer_click = 0
            self.segundo_click = 0

    def mousePresEvent(self, event):
        if self.flag_dibujar == True:
            if self.primer_click == 0 and event.button() == QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
                self.begin = event.pos()
                self.beginX = int(self.begin.x())
                self.beginY= int(self.begin.y()) 

                self.QLabel.update()
                self.primer_click = 1
            else:
                self.end = event.pos()
                self.endX = int(self.end.x())
                self.endY = int(self.end.y())

                self.QLabel.update()
                self.segundo_click = 1
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Yes, I know the mouseMoveEvent, but when I use this method, painter draws rectangles in each position of mouse. I  want only one rectangle that variate his shape since the first click position and confirm this shape with the second click. Do you understand me?